# Where does Visual Studio *download* vsix packages? Can I extract these manually for another machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a `VM` with a lot of `VS`  extensions maybe `~20GB` of downloads if I remember correctly.

This `VM` has become corrupted, however, I can mount the `.vhd` OK and see the `fs` on it.

I have a very slow internet connection (like `56k old skool modem`, maybe worse actually).

I'd like to build a new VM with VS so I can continue as before.

I don't really want to wait for days on end for `20GB` of VS extensions to download.

Q: Can I extract the `vsix` or `msi` files from the `VHD` and copy them to my new VM? Does anyone know where VS downloads these files to? Can I even do this? I just want to get on and not have to re-download these. I do have squid running in the background but the cache size is nothing like 20GB (more like 500 MB) as I'm using old machines for pretty much everything so that is unfortunately not going to help.

Did anyone get any pointers? Even some partial VS package restoration would help me since bandwidth is so limited for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Typical Visual Studio 2015 extensions are installed into the `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions` folder with the corresponding registry entries in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ExtensionManager`.

(Still I don't recommend manually coping it. Extension installers should not exceed 1 GB and you can probably download them using a faster machine and then bring to a new VM.)

Comment: Thanks - not much in the ~\14.0\Extensions folder. I washoping th

Comment: (cont)... I was hoping there would be a (quick or dirty) way to extract the msi or vsix files from the FS to save me having to download them all again as bandwidth is my issue. Pretty sure VS summed up to ~20 GB of downloads for the project types in the solution I'm looking at. Had a quick peek at %WinDir%\installer but alas it looks messy so I don't think this is going to be straight forward (nor reliable). This might be a good idea for a VS extension in the future perhaps..? Not everyone has access to fast internet! And my machines are all ancient since I'm on a tight budget!

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question directly:**
Typically, Visual Studio 2015/2017 will "download" to %AppData%\Local\Temp.
Where %AppData% should be similar to c:\Users\{username}\AppData

Look in this folder for *.vsix files.... they will have unique filenames for **each download**, even if they are the exact same version of an extension. So you will probably have some duplicate extensions.  This also makes it difficult to know what you have.

**However:**
Best option is re-download them as you need them, as *@Surgey Vlasov* has already suggested.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, that if you have ever run any of the disk cleanup tools, this temp folder will usually get purged... so your *.vsix files may not even be on the system anymore...